# Prediction close to a "pole". What can I do?

Tags: prediction

I have x and y related in the way $x = a + \frac{1}{b+y}$.
x is measured.  I am interested in y.  a and b are known.  y *must* be $>=0$ from physics, x is also always $>0$.
Solving for y: $y = \frac{1}{x-a}-b$.

Measurements of x are about normal distributed around some value (1 experiment - several values).
However I'm interested in y. For values close to a things get messy.
But in many cases I have a number of points $<a$ and don't know how to deal with them.

Can you give me pointers what I can do to estimate y in these cases?

**Extra information** - maybe it helps with suggesting a solution.

My aim would be to to calculate y for each experiment with some kind of information about accuracy.  In addition I need to do some kind of summary statistic over all my measurements of y.

- x is a slope - calculated by linear regression,  practically it is in the range from 0 to 1,  typically close to 0.5 (with sd < 1%, but I did not use this so far)
- a and b are assumed as constants calculated from empirical values ( however the values by different researchers disagree by 20% - life sciences  )
- both a and b are >0, also a < 1
- I would assume the distribution of y is similar to a lognormal distribution.

Comment: If you know that y must be greater than zero, then you can put a lower bound on x (and justify this appropriately), such that y will never be non-positive. That is some lower bound below which you justify it as measurement error, since it's not possible.

Comment: I wonder putting the measurement error term like $x_{measured}=x_{true }+e$ could be helpful in this situation. I hope someone will answer this post.

Comment: @user2974951 unfortunately this is only half the problem.  I was already thinking along making a+eps a lower bound for x - but then I will end up with lots of items valued 1/eps.

Comment: Since $a$ and $b$ are known, this is not primarily an estimation problem (as you have tagged it): it appears to be one of *prediction,* if I read your post correctly.  (It is possible you will need to estimate the error variance, but that is a "nuisance parameter" that does not appear of direct interest.)  The solution depends on what you know or assume about $y$ and the error variance.  For instance, is $y$ a random variable with a known distribution?

Comment: @whuber I see - sorry my statistical vocubaulary is rusty.  I will retag.  I also gave some extra information in case it helps suggest an approach.

Comment: Thank you, but now I'm totally mystified, because your question begins with a statement of its solution!  Since you state you know $a$ and $b,$ then for any given $y$ you predict $x$ by plugging the values $a,b,y$ into the formula for it.  The accuracy information comes from analyzing the measurement system.  However, there is much that is mysterious, because evidently you do *not* know $y:$ you estimate it with regression (on data you don't describe).  I have a very strong feeling that you haven't articulated the problem you actually face and the lack of detail might hurt you.

Comment: @whuber - thanks for correcting me - when I wrote I had x and y mixed up.  let me correct. That's what I get for using SE on the go.